# Docker build no No such file or directory

Tags: docker, docker-compose, path, dockerfile

From the directory I am trying to run the command

```
sudo docker-compose -f project/docker/docker-compose.yml up
```

[image: tree]

This is the error I get

```
    ubuntu@ip-172-31-90-166:~/tp3-securite-applicative$ sudo docker-compose -f project/docker/docker-compose.yml up
    Recreating docker_api-service-track-1_1 ... done
    Attaching to docker_api-service-track-1_1
    api-service-track-1_1  | python path is:
    api-service-track-1_1  | //project/
    api-service-track-1_1  | running the following python program
    api-service-track-1_1  | ./project/codeAPI/API.py ./project/codeAPI/front.py
    api-service-track-1_1  | python3: can't open file '//./project/codeAPI/API.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
    api-service-track-1_1  | python3: can't open file '//./project/codeAPI/front.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

This is my Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3
ADD ./run.sh /
ADD ./requirements.txt /
RUN pip3 install -r ./requirements.txt
CMD ["./run.sh", "./project/codeAPI/API.py", "./project/codeAPI/front.py"]
```

This is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  api-service-track-1:
    build:
      context: ../../
      dockerfile: ./project/docker/Dockerfile
    image: img_track1
    volumes:
      - ./:/mnt/app
    ports:
      - 5551:5551
    tty: true
```

I define my python path in my run.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

export PYTHONPATH=$PWD/project/
echo python path is:
echo $PYTHONPATH

echo running the following python program
echo $@
python3 "$1"
python3 "$2"
```

requirements.txt contains a bunch of imports.

I tried multiple ways to adapt my python path by modifying my run.sh and my Dockerfile but I am unable to find my front.py and API.py. Do I not understand the concept of path or am missing something obvious?

edit 1 after Saikiran Rudra correction:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-90-166:~/tp3-securite-applicative$ sudo docker-compose -f project/docker/docker-compose.yml up
Creating network "docker_default" with the default driver
Creating docker_api-service-track-1_1 ... done
Attaching to docker_api-service-track-1_1
api-service-track-1_1  | python path is:
api-service-track-1_1  | //project/
api-service-track-1_1  | running the following python program
api-service-track-1_1  | ./project/codeAPI/API.py ./project/codeAPI/front.py
api-service-track-1_1  | /usr/local/bin/python3: can't find '__main__' module in '//./project/codeAPI/API.py'
api-service-track-1_1  | /usr/local/bin/python3: can't find '__main__' module in '//./project/codeAPI/front.py'
```

Comment: You never `COPY` your code (or the PNG file you included) into the image.

Comment: @DavidMaze Why is that?

Comment: I'm not sure, but adding a line like `COPY project project` might help things along.  You can remove the `volumes:` block in the `docker-compose.yml` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced similar problem try this it worked for me

In docker-compose.yml in volumes section add this lines

```yaml
volumes:
      - ./:/mnt/app
      - /project/codeAPI/API.py
      - /project/codeAPI/front.py
```

Comment: I just did that modification and it detected both my files (which is great!). But now it's looking for the main in both thoses files. I will add it in the edit so you can understand.

Comment: I think you have copied all your file required file to the container try adding this at second line WORKDIR /usr/src/app and COPY . . at last second line of your Dockerfile

Comment: That did it! Thank you. If you have time can you explain what the line COPY . . means in my Dockerfile?

Comment: The first statement ```WORKDIR /usr/src/app``` set the directory location(for container), which means all the relative paths you specify after that would be with respect to that path and then ```COPY . .``` what this does is copies all the file in your current project directory(in your file system) to the directory you specified first that WORKDIR one. here copying means copying from your file system to container file system